# c# Storing a generic reference to have self updating snapshots

Tags: c#, generics, snapshot, state-machine, ref

I have a class called "RelativeData" that is used for comparing values through a state machine. I am trying to build a class that takes snapshots of the data at given intervals. The intervals being: StateBegins, StateMachineBegins, and the one I'm having issue with, liveValue.
The challenge im having is the liveValue(s) I wish to track are in a separate class, There is a large list of values I want to add to track with my RelativeData objects, so my class needs to be generic.

the point of this class is to take snapshots of data.

```
class RelativeData<T>
{ 
   T initialValue;
   T stateValue;
   T liveValue;  //currently not implemented, since i can't store a ref

   public void StateMachineActive(T curValue)
   {
     initialValue = curValue;
   }
   public void StateUpdated(T curValue)
   {
      stateValue = curValue;
   }
}
```

ex) a `float` called "energy" which belongs to a spell. When the state machine activates, it calls `StateMachineActive` on my list of relativeData, which preferably could internally update using liveValue, instead of having to pass curValue

Current fix)
I have a manager that adds these values to dictionaries of the generic types.
`Dictionary<myKey,relativeData<bool>> relativeBoolData`
`Dictionary<myKey,relativeData<float>> relativeFloatData`
& etc...
However to call StateUpdated, i need to pass the current value, which i need to get from a large switch case using myKey. Doable, but back in C++ days I could just store a T*. Can't turn on unsafe mode since Unity doesn't seem to allow it. I could have the actual values just stored in there, but then everytime I want to get the currentValue (which happens ALOT more often than getting a relative value) everywhere throughout the code, it would increase complexity(be more proc heavy). At least I assume.

Question:
1) Can I store a pointer to a Icomparable type? Can I have liveValue point to a valueType/Primitive data type (ie int, long, enum) elsewhere, like I could in C++ with T*. I know I can pass using "ref" but I can't seem to store it.

2) Should I just store the actual values in there instead, and have everything be retreived through a two tier switch case (First to know which dict to call, the float, bool... and then to retrive the value) would that not increase runtime too heavily? The non-relative values: energy, stability, etc, are used continuously in spells for internal calculations. The relative only used for state machine. (may have 2~60 spells active at once)

3) Is this just a bad pattern, is there a better pattern that I am just not seeing, a better way to take snapshots of generic data?

4) I know arrays are by ref, but that would mean my original data would all have to become arrays right?

5) Should I just leave it the way it is. It works, just a tad messier and slower.

all of them are `IComparable`: ints, floats, bools, enums..

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the following:

- Create a wrapper class for the values and keep a reference on the wrapper.

  ```
  public class Wrapper<T>
  {
      public T Value { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Store the values in an array and remember the indexes instead of the values themselves.
- Store the values in a dictionary and remember their keys instead of the values themselves.
- Store an accessor delegate (`Func<T>`). Note: Lambda expressions automatically keep a reference on the context in which they were first declared. See [The Beauty of Closures](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx) (by Jon Skeet).